# Ajax and php - login script

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to do a login page, but I have an issue wit ajax method:

```
 $("#login").click(function(){

        username=$("#user_name").val();
        password=$("#password").val();
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data: {name : username, pwd : password},
            success: function(html){
              if( ($.trim(html)) =='true')
              {
                $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
                        $("#shadow").fadeOut();
                        $("#profile").html("<a href='logout.php' id='logout'>Logout</a>");

              }
              else
              {
                    $("#add_err").html("Wrong username or password");
              }
            },
            beforeSend:function()
                {
                 $("#add_err").html("Loading...")
            }
        });
         return false;
    });
```

**login.php:**

```
<?php  

 session_start();

 $username = $_POST['name'];
 //$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
 $password = ($_POST['pwd']);
 //$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);

 $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','peer');
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
 $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 if( $num_row >=1 ) {
  echo 'true';
  $_SESSION['user_name']=$row['username'];
 }
 else{
 echo 'false';
 }
?>
```

I'm posting to login.php username and password, but obviously get nothing back, when I tried execute only php script it works correct. A html object seems like is still `false`.
Do you see any mistake here ??

thanks

EDIT!

Comment: Did you try just echoing back the username and password to check that you receive them ? And you can change the data in ajax to : `data: {name : username, pwd : password},` and try doing this `if( $.trim(html) =='true') {...`

Comment: it doesn't work, 
I just learn to use ajax and connect to db..

Answer (score 2):

These are the issues I see here

- your data mat not be properly encoded. Instead of `data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,` use `data:{name:username,pwd:password}` so that jQuery will properly encode it for you.
- you response may have leading or trailing white spaces, so try `if($.trim(html)=='true')`
- always validate/sanitize input, you should use [parameterized prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), or at least [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) the fields.

Comment: @user1726810 from your comment on the other answer, it looks like you never even reach `login.php`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#add_err").html("Loading...");
$.post('login.php',
    {'username': username, 'pwd': password},
    function(html){
        $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
        $("#shadow").fadeOut();
        $("#profile").html("<a href='logout.php' id='logout'>Logout</a>");
    }
);
```

@Musa pointed out that you shouldn't pass POST variables with

```
"name="+username+"&pwd="+password, use data:{name:username,pwd:password}
```

and he's 100% correct.

Another trick that might help is to use:

```
console.log(variable);
```

Whatever variable you pass will be returned to the console. You can view the console by pressing F12 in whatever browser your using. You could pass username and password before the ajax call is made, that way you can see if you're actually getting the user's input. You could also console.log the html variable, that would show if you're getting a response from the server.

Comment: it doesn't work and `console.log(html);` get me `Object {auth: false}`

Comment: I just edited the script, replaced password with pwd. What might be the problem is using $mysqli->real_escape_string. I feel like md5 would eliminate any malicious code (I could be wrong). Try it without the real_escape_string.

Comment: You could also use console.log even further. Commenting out PHP code step by step may help you. Only echoing one variable at a time helps me a lot, I would start with $result, and then $num_row, and then $row

Comment: I just edit my current version and how can I console.log() php variable ??

Comment: Let's say (in the PHP file) you only echo one variable. For example 'echo $result', you could then use (in the Javascript) console.log(html), that way you'll be able to see the what the server says is $result

Comment: yes I understand, but echo $result, I don't see in console. And definitely php script work fine